# Zoom MapView to show annotations across 180th meridian

Tags: swift, maps, mkmapview, mapkit, coordinates

I have a MapView with <5 annotations. When the map loads, I want to zoom in to center the map on these annotations, like [this](https://gist.github.com/andrewgleave/915374). However, the linked method doesn't work when the annotations are spread across the 180th meridian (where longitude wraps from -180 to +180). How can I robustly zoom to the annotations even if they are clustered around the prime meridian?

For example, if I have x(0,179) and y(0,-179) then I'd want a containing rect with a width of two degrees longitude, not 358.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapKit for iOS actually has a built-in function in MKMapView which does this:

```
showAnnotations(annotations: [MKAnnotation], animated: Bool)
```

However, this function doesn't offer control over the zoom level, so I still had to make my own function. Here is the pseudocode:

```
zoomToAnnotations(annotations, zoomLimit) {
    // calculate the midpoint as the average latitude and longitude
    average_latitude = mean(a.coordinate.latitude for a in annotations)
    average_longitude = atan2(mean(sin(a.coordinate.longitude) for a in annotations), mean(cos(a.coordinate.longitude) for a in annotations)) // be careful with degrees and radians in real code
    regular_midpoint = coordinate(average_latitude, average_longitude)
    // subtract 180 from longitude for the midpoint of the region crossing the meridian
    meridian_midpoint = coordinate(average_latitude, average_longitude - 180.0)
    if (meridian_midpoint.longitude < -180) {
        meridian_midpoint.longitude += 360.0
    }

    // work out which region will be smaller and center map there
    meridian_sum = sum(a.coordinate.distance(meridian_midpoint) for a in annotations)
    regular_sum = sum(a.coordinate.distance(regular_midpoint) for a in annotations)
    regular_max_distance = max(a.coordinate.distance(regular_midpoint) for a in annotations)
    if meridian_sum < regular_sum {
        meridian_max_distance = max(a.coordinate.distance(meridian_midpoint) for a in annotations)
        centerMapWithRadius(meridian_midpoint, max(zoomLimit, meridian_max_distance))
    } else {
       regular_max_distance = max(a.coordinate.distance(regular_midpoint) for a in annotations)
        centerMapWithRadius(regular_midpoint, max(zoomLimit, regular_max_distance))
    }
}
```

This method isn't perfect , as it centers on the mean of the points instead of having the furthest points equal distances from the edge.